# Apple Pages insert equation greyed out after 8.1 update

Tags: pages

I've been using Pages' insert equation functionality to insert LaTeX equations for a long time now. However, recently after the new update I am unable to do so as the option is greyed out. 
[image]

I tried copy-pasting an equation from one of my older files just to see if I can edit it. And I can! [image]

Not sure why I cannot insert new equations though. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact problem too, and after about 24 hours of frantic searching and panic, I found a solution.

Install MathType.  Just the trial is fine.  Open Pages, go into Preferences, and uncheck "Insert equations with MathType."  Without MathType, this option is obviously greyed out and unchecked, but installing MathType checks it by default.

You should now be able to insert equations using the built-in editor.  You can uninstall MathType and it will continue to work, or has for me at least.